# How to insert a GridSplitter row between each item in a bound dynamic collection

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, gridsplitter

I have a one column grid, with rows of varying heights in a WPF application. The items in the grid are dynamically generated, and will be added and removed at run-time.

For each row that is added, I would like a GridSplitter row to be inserted between each element.

I currently bind the model data via an ItemControl, and use AttachedProperties to obtain the element row count (obviously the eventual solution will have a higher number of rows to include the GridSplitters):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyModel}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding MyModel.RowCount}" local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The MyModel variable is an ObservableCollection which contains ViewModel objects. The RowCount is a member variable which returns the number of elements in the collection.

How can I insert a GridSplitter between each of the rows?

I would like each element and GridSplitter to be generated from a template. However, if the GridSplitter is contained within a template, it doesn't work due to the presence of a ContentPresenter as its parent rather than a Grid. I'm running out of ideas, apart from creating my own UI element which has its own splitter component written from scratch. There must be an other way surely!

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a considerable amount of reading, I think I have found the best solution, for those who may wish to do the same thing.

I implemented something similar to how the ColumnResizerAdorner works in the core WPF library. It may also be worth looking at the ResizingAdorner example in MSDN's WPF sample.

I have a class for the adorning, which adds a Thumb to a VisualCollection. A class for handling thumb dragging events. This class is aware of the Grid row definitions, and resizes them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `GridHelpers` static class defining the `RowCount` property is responsible for dynamically generating new `RowDefinition` for each item in the `ItemsSource`.

For 2nd item and all subsequent ones, instead of adding a `RowDefinition` your code should add two row definitions - one for the item and one for the splitter.  Then the code should also add a gridsplitter with Grid.Row value of the first of the two RowDefinitions you dynamically add.  It would always be odd.

```
    var gs = new GridSplitter();
    gs.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, x); //x = the RowDefinition you are generating
    gs.ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.PreviousAndNext;
    gs.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    gs.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    gs.Height = 3; //or whatever other height you desire.
```

Then add another RowDefinition for the item itself.   Don't forget to set the Grid.Row property for the item to the even rowdefinition

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this within XAML? I was looking at DataTemplates in-conjunction with a TemplateSelector as a potential solution.

Comment: Jon, I don't think it's completely in XAML now.  You have those attached properties defined in the GridHelpers class (local:GridHelpers).  I suspect the current rowdefinition generation logic is there.  I simply suggested amending it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was probably getting too hung up on implementing it XAML! It's given me a direction to go in.

Comment: By using the code in user195275's answer in combination gives the error "Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel." at run-time. This happens when adding a GridSplitter to the grid in code (or just doing grid.Children.clear()). Is there a way round this?

Comment: No problem at all - having read a couple of articles, I think it's because I'm trying to modify the Item template directly in code, which isn't allowed. The code is in the GridHelpers class. I can add/remove row/column definitions ok, but can't change the children. I also tried making it a Style and applying it to the Grid object, but I couldn't get that to work either! I expect taking it out of the Item template and creating my own ItemsSource property on the GridHelpers class will probably work ok, but doesn't seem quite as clean... unless there's another way? ;)

Comment: I understand the problem now. There may be another way. I'll try is before posting it. Will chime back.